# Can you convert an iOS freemium app to a paid app without double-charging customers?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

The scenario is:

- I created a free iOS app that had in-app purchases for premium content
- I now want to convert the app into a paid only version of it and remove all IAP stuff

My questions are:

1. Will the AppStore let all current customers download the app again without double-charging them? (i.e. forcing them to pay for an app that used to be free)
2. As long as I keep the bundle identifier (i.e. com.yourcompanyname.appname) the same, it will just overwrite the old app like a normal upgrade, correct?

Comment: Questions on Super User are generally supposed to relate to computer hardware or software. This question is off topic here.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. @IWasRobbed. Perhaps it is suited for Programmers.SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct: if it's the same app -- same bundle id, submitted as an update -- then existing customers will be able to download it for free forever, like any upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted reassurance before possibly upsetting many loyal customers :)

Comment: Curious, though, that you're also going to be giving the new paid-only app to all customers, *including* those who downloaded the freemium app, but never paid to unlock the freemium features.  You're aware of this right?

Comment: Fair nuff, just wanted to make sure you were aware of the consequences.

Comment: that changed recently when Apple introduced the purchased receipt inside the app. Now you can check if the user purchased the inapp and block users that haven't.